# Top 3 most visited pages in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to show top 3 most visited pages in my home page of sharepoint site. I need to find out the Title of the Top 3 pages and display them in a link. I found out the way. But it display all the pages like allpages.aspx, settings.aspx... I need only top 3 most user created pages. So far I have been unable to figure out the best way to do this. Any suggestions to get me started would be appreciated.

Regards,
Raji...

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom Web Analytics Web Part derived from OOTB WAWP. Check some solution here: http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/sharepoint-2010-display-titles-instead-of-url%E2%80%99s-in-whatspopularwebpart/

In your custom code you can make filtration functionality and skip undesired pages.